# Play framework 1.4.2 throws ClassNotFoundException when precompile app with modules

Tags: java, playframework, module, hazelcast, precompile

We have an application which is built using [playframework 1.4.2](http://playframework.com/documentation/1.4.x) and uses [play-hazelcast](https://www.playframework.com/modules/hazelcast) module, java version is "1.8.0_91".

My application uses hazelcast distributed topic for message exchange between nodes. There are totally four nodes. When I start my application in normal mode with sources, everything works fine, but if I try ti run in precompiled mode it throws ClassNotFoundException, I can't understand where is the root of the problem in the play framework or hazelcast module?

The play-hazelcast plugin:

https://github.com/braman/hazelcast

dependencies.yml:

```
# Application dependencies
require:
    - play 
    - hazelcast     -> hazelcast  latest.integration
    - org.hibernate -> hibernate-search 4.3.0.Final

repositories:
    - hazelcast:
        type: local
        artifact: ${application.path}/../hazelcast
        contains:
            - hazelcast -> *
```

Here is the exception:

```
WARNING: [10.0.0.167]:5799 [prod] [3.7.1] Error while logging processing event
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pojo.system.events.StatusChangedEvent
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:224)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:46)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:172)
    at com.hazelcast.topic.impl.DataAwareMessage.getMessageObject(DataAwareMessage.java:44)
    at jobs.StartupJob$1.onMessage(StartupJob.java:72)
    at com.hazelcast.topic.impl.TopicService.dispatchEvent(TopicService.java:134)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.eventservice.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:48)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.eventservice.impl.RemoteEventProcessor.run(RemoteEventProcessor.java:36)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.StripedExecutor$Worker.process(StripedExecutor.java:187)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.StripedExecutor$Worker.run(StripedExecutor.java:171)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pojo.system.events.StatusChangedEvent
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.tryLoadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:151)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:120)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.IOUtil$ClassLoaderAwareObjectInputStream.resolveClass(IOUtil.java:358)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:219)
    ... 9 more
```

This exception means that a message was received my hazelcast module, but it couldn't deserialize it because the class was not found.

Comment: I am not sure. I am using the Play framework recently. But I know that classNotFoundExceptions are usually thrown because of an bad import. Try to look if you use the correct import

Comment: If the import was incorrect then precompile command would throw an error during compile time.

Comment: What kind of dependency management are you using? Is it maven? Did you check the scope (compile, test, runtime) in which you included this library?

Comment: I've updated my question and added dependencies.yml. PlayFramework uses its own mechanism of dependency management, I guess it is based on Ivy.